# Testing for function from variable

Tags: javascript, function, call, typeof

Inside a function I need to test if another variable function exists and then call it if it does.

```
function div1_load(){
  // do something
}

function main(id){
  var func = id + '_load';
  if (func is function) {
    func.call();
  }
}
main('div1');
```

I can think of two ways to test, but both involve eval() which I would like to avoid.

1. typeof eval(func) === 'function'
2. eval('typeof(' + func + ')') === 'function'

Is there a way without using eval() ?
If not, which of my two methods is most secure ?

Comment: Why does it need to be a variable? Can it have different values? If so, why is the function a global instead of a member of a data structure (e.g. `{ div1_load: function () { ... }, div2_load....}`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to execute a JavaScript function when I have its name as a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359788/how-to-execute-a-javascript-function-when-i-have-its-name-as-a-string)

Comment: Typical to find the answer after posting. @Quentin: div1_load() is not always defined, and there is no data structure because its being kept simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function main(id, ns) {
    if (!ns) {
        ns = window;
    }
    if (typeof ns[id + '_load'] === "function") {
        ns[id + '_load']();
    }
}

function div1_load() {
    alert("div1_load() was called");
}

main('div1');

var test = {
    div1_load: function() {
        alert("test.div1_load() was called");
    }
};

main('div1', test);​
```

Comment: I found it here after I posted. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359788/how-to-execute-a-javascript-function-when-i-have-its-name-as-a-string

Comment: What if the function is not global nor belongs to an object? Like, `(function() { function test() {} function main() { /* does test() exist? */ }());`

Comment: @FlorianMargaine: see edit. As for your example, the outer function is an anonymous function; probing its inner functions (IMO) makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the functions are global (i.e. belonging to `window` object, you can just check the `typeof`:

```
if(typeof window[id] === 'function') {  }
```

Comment: What if the function is not global nor belongs to an object? Like, `(function() { function test() {} function main() { /* does test() exist? */ }());`

Comment: I think you may be SOL, I'm afraid. The namespace to which the function is assigned is anonymous; isn't that the whole point of using closures?

Answer (score 1):

if the function is assigned within the global namespace (`window`), you can check for a function name string being a function by using `window[function name] instanceof Function`. If it's assigned within a (pseudo) namespace, use `SomeNamespace[function name]`. In other words, a function can be retrieved as a property/method from a namespace (global (`window` in a browser), or defined in your code).

```
function div1_load(){
  // do something
}

function main(id){
  if (window[id+'_load'] instanceof Function) {
    window[id+'_load'].call();
  }
}
main('div1')
```

[**edit based on comment**] In case of an anonymous, immediately instantiated function, this won't work. The example from @Florian Margaine could be adjusted this way though:

```
var MyPersonalNamespace = (function() {
  function test() {}
  function main(someid) { 
     if (this[someid] instanceof Function){
       this[someid].call();
     }
  }
  return {test: test, main: main};
 }());
 MyPersonalNamespace.main('test');
```

Comment: What if the function is not global nor belongs to an object? Like, `(function() { function test() {} function main() { /* does test() exist? */ }());`